# php $_files['name'] returns only extension no name

Tags: php, file, post, postman

According to my problem I have some files.
Those have strange name. though those files name are strange I need to read them and process for move to my destination.
I am using PHP
my files name like this  **`\223\214\222\267\215\350\207\\.pdf`**

Here is my php code after post that file

```
$userfile_name = $_FILES;
```

I am getting output like this

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => .pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpPgcA2r
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 11864025
        )

)
```

Here problem is I am not getting exact file name

Comment: https://libguides.princeton.edu/c.php?g=102546&p=930626

Answer (score 1):

Your filename `\223\214\222\267\215\350\207\\.pdf` is surely read as file in the UNIX system, so you get the last part of it (the `.pdf`). It's a feature and it works fine in 99,9% of the cases. Please use other filename (or escape underscores on your own before uploading file).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved my problem by myself using . new CurlFile($filedata, $filetype, $filename); here $filename = 'clean_report.pdf'; //to prevent unix type name